# PHP Message send page to same page pop up box

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

My website has a contact form using HTML and PHP. when the user presses the send button, it goes to a success page. How would I change this to turn into a pop up message on the same page as the contact form? Here is my code:

```
<section id="contact" class="main style3 blue">
            <div class="content container">

                <header>
                    <h2>Say Hello.</h2>
                    <p>You can use the form below to contact us regariding any form of inquiry</p>
                </header>
                <div class="box container 75%">

                <!-- Contact Form -->
                        <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="row 50%">
                                <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
                                <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row 50%">
                                <div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message (Please include your telephone number)" rows="6"></textarea></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="12u">
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
$name        = $_POST['name'];
$email       = $_POST['email'];
$phone       = $_POST['phone'];
$message     = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = " From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message \n Email: $email";
$recipient   = "email@email.com";
$subject     = "Message from the Site";
$mailheader  = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='/1/' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'><strong> Return Home</strong></a>";
?>
```

Comment: You need use ajax call , keep the success message in a div using css property display : none and show the message on the success of ajax call by changing display : block